# PowerShell - Create new instance with different credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to create a new PowerShell instance out of my script with different user credentials.
My idea is to do in this script part some admin stuff with different credentials. I want to execute the main part with normal user privileges.

Idea, but not working:

```
$script= {$InScript = Get-Process}

$pp= get-credential

[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "c:\windows\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "-command $script", $pp.UserName.Split('\')[1] , $pp.Password , $pp.UserName.Split('\')[0] )

[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "-command $script", $pp.UserName.Split('\')[1] , $pp.Password , $pp.UserName.Split('\')[0] )


$InScript
```

Exception at both lines with start commands:

> Exception calling "Start" with "5" argument(s): "The directory name is
>   invalid"

When I´m executing the script with admin privileges, it´s working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .net:

```
$pp= get-credential # as domain\username and password

[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "powershell.exe", "-command $script", $pp.UserName.Split('\')[1] , $pp.Password , $pp.UserName.Split('\')[0] )
```

This is the Constructor of `::Start` method:

```
::Start(string fileName, string arguments, string userName, System.Security.SecureString password, string domain)
```

Edit After comment:

try put full path to the exe:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "-command $script", $pp.UserName.Split('\')[1] , $pp.Password , $pp.UserName.Split('\')[0] )
```

or use start-process:

```
start-process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Credential $pp -ArgumentList $script
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But I´m getting a execption. Exception calling "Start" with "5" argument(s): "The directory name is invalid" At line:2 char:36

Comment: Post the line that give error. It seem to be some error in the path of executable..

Comment: PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "powershell.exe", "-command $script"
, $pp.UserName.Split('\')[1] , $pp.Password , $pp.UserName.Split('\')[0] )
Exception calling "Start" with "5" argument(s): "The directory name is invalid"
At line:1 char:36
+ [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start <<<< ( "powershell.exe", "-command $script", $pp.UserName.Split('\')[1] , $pp.Pas
sword , $pp.UserName.Split('\')[0] )
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Oh thanks! Admin privileges fixed the problem with the exception. But in my case I want to run a script as normal user and run the $script with other privileges. Is there a workaround to run a new powershell instance without admin privileges?

Comment: Have you try passing full path?